# VueJS + Electron, building issue with API

Tags: api, vue.js, electron

I have an issue:

I'm working on an app in Electron-Vue, and to test if it works outside of the "npm run dev", I build it, and launched. The app runs well but as soon as I try to connect on the ui end with a random session (doing an API call), the app does nothing.
When I click to get a random page which does'nt need API call, it works well and redirects me to the correct page, but when it needs to make an API call, it suddenly fail and doesn't do anything at all.
Do you know how I can track errors in build mode or do you have an idea of what's going on ?

NB : I use electron-vue builder

Thanks a lot ^^

Comment: I'd recommend starting here: create a build that launches with devtools open and see if you can find anything there - console errors, network calls, etc.

Comment: Do you know where and how to put it ? (package.json ? electron index.js ?) I'm a bit confused about how to do it ^^'

Comment: In whatever function you create your window object, you can call the `webContents.openDevTools()` function on the window object to launch devtools. In the application I'm working on, this call is right after declaring the window (`win = new BrowserWindow(windowOptions);`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, after a quick lookup, I've found an answer to this.

https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/issues/214

Here, in the case of electron-vue, this can be used to easily get a console while just entering a manual command on your keyboard !